# How is teamkilling penalized in BF3?

Tags: battlefield-3

Is there an anti-TK system in the game? How can I punish somebody who intentionally killed me? Is there some kind of slap or slay system?

Comment: I just had a flashback to playing TFC 12 years ago when you said "slap or slay".

Comment: Yeah some kind of slap or slay would be nice... but I will say that I seem to have "problems" with the friendly icons in hardcore mode... they just show up a bit after your turned a corner and spotted som guy barreling down on you...

Comment: @Holger: If you are aware of the team (US / RU) you are on, then it is mostly easy to differentiate between friend and foe looking at his outfit.

Comment: @Bora That is, until they add in hats! What FPS worth its money doesn't have hats!

Comment: @Bora: Well actually I don't find it that easy to differentiate between the US / RU uniforms... but that might just be me or the faster gameplay on hardcore...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an anti-team-killing setup on the *server* side of things. Server admins can adjust these as they see fit, but if you team kill enough you'll get booted.

This is what the defaults look like:

[image]

Comment: Do you know what typical values are set to? I don't think "A player is forgiven for one teamkill in 0.5 seconds" is reasonable at all.

Comment: My guess is they are left at default right now by the majority of server admins. give it another month or so for people to see how these values work out. It's a balancing act, you want to penalize intentional TKs w/o too severely penalizing unintentional TKs

Answer (score 3):

There is a server side setting that causes you to be kicked from the server after a certain amount of team kills. This is obviously decided by the server owner, so some servers will have it set very low (maybe even 1 if they're extremely picky) while some will give you lots of freedom (maybe set it to 50?)

[image: Server Settings]

Answer (score 1):

There is no anti-TK system in the game itself, but I expect this to come in a future update.

We all do.. *gives the MW3 fraction a leering look*

Answer (score 0):

On PC some servers with the appropriate plugin adopt the following: typing `!punish` into the chat window after getting tk'ed will punish the offender. Similarly forgiving is `!forgive`

you can also `!votekick`

[Insane Punisher](http://www.phogue.net/forumvb/showthread.php?1069-Insane-Punisher) provides such functionality for PC Servers.

These were all seemingly standard commands on the original Battlefield/Desert Combat servers I played on, not sure if everyone just added in the mods or whether they were in fact standard on the original.